# Using Microsoft Paint with Matlab Code

Tags: image, matlab

I need to have a few hundred photos manually inspected and edited.
Certain things need to be blacken out, while others marked in various ways.

I would like to write a script/GUI that will allow me to do the following:

1) Open mspaint

2) load image (uint8 matrix) currently saved in workspace into open session

3) when done editing, close mspaint and save new image into workspace (as uint8 matrix)

**to implement this, I wish to know:**

- How to load an image from workspace into an open mspaint session.
- How to save an image from a mspaint session to workspace as uint8 matrix.
- How to close mspaint - openning is with "system('mspaint')"

Help would be much appriciated.

Thanks, Alon

Comment: I realize this isn't an answer to the technical challenge you have, but as an alternative to writing your own, have you considered using image annotation software?    I've used LabelImg quite a bit before and it works well.  Wikipedia has list of many tool, many of which are free or open source.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_manual_image_annotation_tools

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. Unfortunately this task is a part of a much larger construct which already has a Matlab GUI running it, and so the ask is to incorporate the solution into the GUI. Still, I will look into what you have suggested and see if I can find a software similar to paint which I can hook with Matlab. Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MSPaint doesn't have an API, however, you can pass a filename to it as a command line argument.

The downside to this approach is that the user is responsible for saving the image back to the same location and exiting MSPaint after editing the image.

```
function im = edit_in_paint(im)
    temp_filename = [tempname, '.png'];
    imwrite(im, temp_filename);
    system(['mspaint.exe ' temp_filename]);
    im = imread(temp_filename);
    delete(temp_filename)
```

**Example**

```
>> im = imread('rice.png');
>> im = edit_in_paint(im);
```

(MSPaint opens)

[image]

**Edit image, then save (Ctrl+s) and exit to return to MATLAB**

```
>> imshow(im);
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you jodag. Do you know of a similar program to MSPaint I could use, which will allow me to have the user save and close the session through the GUI?

Comment: I'm not familiar with any editors which could be used such a way easily within MATLAB. If you want something with such specific behavior then the easiest approach may be to implement your own annotation tool in MATLAB.

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much for your help.